# Error: Error creating WebGL context - Jasmine-spie

Tags: javascript, angular, three.js, karma-jasmine

I am writing a unit test for one of the methods that instantiate a class new THREE.WebGLRenderer' and throws an Error: Error creating WebGL context`

```
public init(element: HTMLElement) { 
  this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}); 
}
```

so I decided to mock THREE.WebGLRenderer as

```
jasmine.createSpy('THREE.WebGLRenderer').and.returnValue(mockRenderer);
```

but when I call init method it again instantiates new THREE.WebGLRenderer and throws the same error.

Someone please suggest to fix the error or help me to mock it.